# Maximum call stack size exceeded React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have error `maximum call stack size exceeded`. Maybe I in wrong way understand `componentDidUpdate`, but shouldn't it's run one time, instead 1000. How fix it?

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: 0
    }
  }

  updateAmout() {
    let number = 0;
    this.props.comments.map((comment, index) => {

      if (comment.replyTo === null) {

        number += 1;
        this.setState({amount: number});
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updateAmout();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateAmout();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.amount);
    return (
      <div className="comments-container">
        <div id="comments">
          <AddComment />
          <div className="comments-flow">
            <div className="comments-header">
              <div className="pull-right">
                <a href="" className="text-muted">Best</a> |
                <a href="" className="active">Newest</a> |
                <a href="" className="text-muted">Oldest</a>
              </div>
              <b>6 Comments</b>
            </div>
            <RenderComments />
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-block">More...</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    ) // return
  } // render
} // App
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` will force an update which will trigger `componentDidUpdate` which will force again an update and so on.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate()` is a callback to notify you that the state update was finished successfully. You should not trigger another state update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I need to use the `nextProps` argument and the method `componentWillUpdate` instead of the `componentDidUpdate` method.

```js
// before
componentDidUpdate() {
 this.updateAmout();
}

// after
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (!_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps)) {
    this.updateAmout();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Each time you modify state in **`componentDidUpdate`**, a re-render is thrown asynchronously.
In your method `updateAmount`, you are modifying the state. 
And you are calling that method in `componentDidUpdate`, so you initiate an infinite loop of re-renders, so this endless loop created finally wastes the javascript memory.

The React cycle when updating the state is the following one. So you can easily understand why you enter into an endless loop.
[image]

Comment: how i can fix it?

Comment: Execute `updateAmount` after a javascript event (a click, for example) and redo some of the logic. You can also use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check if the re-render might be executed, though it is not good for performance.

Comment: @RamzanChasygov What are you trying to accomplish?